# What and where is SDL2_image?

Tags: qemu, sdl

I am trying to compile QEMU. When issuing 
`../qemu/configure --disable-werror --enable-debug \   --target-list="arm-softmmu,i386-softmmu"`
it outputs

```
 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2  -lSDL2 -lX11
  -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2   -lSDL2 -lX11 -lSDL2_image -lX11
  ...
```

Running make afterwards results in

```
...
  LINK    arm-softmmu/qemu-system-arm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2_image
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:198: recipe for target 'qemu-system-arm' failed
make[1]: *** [qemu-system-arm] Error 1
Makefile:202: recipe for target 'subdir-arm-softmmu' failed
make: *** [subdir-arm-softmmu] Error 2
```

Where can I find SDL2_image?

Comment: `sudo apt install libsdl2-image-dev`

Comment: or --disable-sdl if don't want it anyway (recently mostly gtk is used)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:

```
$ find /usr/lib -name 'libSDL2_*'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image-2.0.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_test.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0.2.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so

$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so
libsdl2-image-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so
```

So it should be provided by the `libsdl2-image-dev` package for your architecture